# How to get .apk file from /bin/folder?

Tags: android, apk

My .apk in bin folder does not function properly when I install it in my android device why ? How can I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: My be the file is corrupted. Try un install and get a new one

Comment: where are you testing it?

Comment: Clean and build again then run .If still problem tell what happens when u are installing on device.

Comment: I uninstalled and installed it again. The facebook login part in the app doesnt work